# How to read the standard istream buffer in c++?

Tags: c++, stream, buffer

I have the following problem. I have to implement a class that has an attribute that is a char  pointer meant to point to the object's "code", as follows:

```
class foo{
     private:
         char* cod;
         ...
     public:
         foo();
         void getVal();
         ...
}
```

So on, so forth. getVal() is a method that takes the code from the standard istream and fills in all the information, including the code. The thing is, the "code" that identifies the object can't be longer than a certain number of characters. This has to be done without using customized buffers for the method getVal(), so I can't do the following:

```
//suppose the maximum number of characters is 50
void foo::getVal()
{
     char buffer[100];
     cin >> buffer;
     if (strlen(buffer) > 50) //I'm not sure this would work considering how the stream
                               of characters would be copied to buffer and how strlen
                               works, but suppose this tells me how long the stream of 
                               characters was.
     {
        throw "Exception";
     }
     ...
}
```

This is forbidden. I also can't use a customized istream, nor the boost library.

I thought I could find the place where istream keeps its information rather easily, but I can't find it. All I've found were mentions to other types of stream.

Can somebody tell me if this can be done or where the stream keeps its buffered information?

Thanks

Comment: If you have a certain number of characters you want, I think you want the `read` method.

Comment: Voting to close as too localized.  The restrictions are arbitrary and not applicable to the real world.

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to do? You want to read a code from a stream. What is the format of the code?

Comment: The thing is that I want to be able to throw an exception if the user doesn't comply with the 20 characters restriction. Would the read method cut the user input short?

Comment: `in.read(buffer, n)` reads up to `n` characters from `in` into `buffer`. If the file terminates earlier than that, less characters are read. The function returns the number of characters it managed to read. I realize that this is a homework assignment (and the question should be tagged as such) but you haven't mentioned the information on what you are really supposed to do! Are you meant to directly use the stream buffer, read characters individually from from stream, use stream iterators...?

Comment: It's not really homework. I'm trying to build a program that wouldn't use unnecessary variables and memory. I guessed that getting rid of the local variables in the Get method would be a fine way to tune the algorithm, resource-usage wise. The thing I'm trying to make doesn't specify anything I told you: I just want to see if there is a way to access the standard input stream buffer to check if its length is smaller than a certain number. By the way, using cin.read(buffer, N) won't work, it just takes the N first characters of the line, leaves the rest in the buffer. I need to cut the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes using strlen would work definitely ..you can write a sample program

```
   int main()
   {

    char buffer[10];
    std::cout << "enter buffer:" ;
    std::cin >>buffer;
    if(strlen(buffer)>6)
    std::cout << "size > 6";
    getch();
   }
```

for inputs greater than size 6 characters it will display size >6

Comment: Don't forget to set the width, otherwise you'll get a buffer overflow. `std::cin >> std::setw(10) >> buffer;`

Comment: No, no. I have that prohibited. I must deal with the problem manipulating the istream object. I give that example as a way to solve this that I can't use.

Comment: @Heathcliff YOU CAN DISPLAY A WARNING IN THAT CASE TO USER THAT STRING SIZE SHOULD NOT EXCEED THE FOLLOWING LENGTH AND IF USER DONT ADHERE TO IT YOU CAn keep it in a While loop until user is forcefully made to enter less than or equal to the size  you have kept. That can be one other way

Answer (score 0):

uhm .... `>>` reads up to the first blank, while strlen counts up to the first null. They can be mixed if you know for sure no blanks are in the middle of string you're going to read and that there are no more than 100 consecutive characted. If not, you will overrun the buffer before throwing.

Also, accessing the buffer does not grant all the string to be already there (the string can go past the buffer space, requiring to partially read and refill the buffer...)

If blanks are separator, why not just read into an `std::string`, and react to its final state? All the dynamics above are already handled inside `>>` for std::string.

[EDIT after the comments below]

The only way to store a sequence of unknown size, is to dynamically allocate the space and make it grow as it is required to grow. This is, no more - no less, what sting and vector do.

Whether you use them or write your own code to allocate and reallocate where more space is required, doesn't change the substance.

I'm start thinking the only reason of those requirements is to see your capability in writing your own string class. So ... just write it:

declare a class holding a pointer a size and a capacity, allocate some space, track how much you store, and when no store is available, allocate another wider store, copy the old, destroy it, and adjust the data member accordingly.

Accessing directly the file buffer is not the way, since you don't control how the file buffer is filled in.

Comment: No, I can't use that solution. I have to deal directly with the istream object and the attribute, no use of internal buffers in the method, unless it's to manipulate the istream buffer (e.g. doing a cast).

Comment: Also, I can't use the standard C++ containers, so no vectors or strings.

Answer (score -1):

An [`istream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) uses a [`streambuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf).

I find that [www.cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) is a pretty good place for quick C++ references. You can go there to see how to use a `streambuf` or its derivative `filebuf`.

Comment: OK. I read about that and I had a few doubts. The standard istream object has a member function called rdbuf that gets the associated stream buffer, that returns a pointer to a streambuf object. It has a method called sbumpc, that returns the character currently pointed by the get pointer. If I understand how these things work correctly, could I use cin.rdbuf()->sbumpc() to compare what's the last character entered that wasn't stored in the attribute "code"? As in, seeing if cin.rdbuf()->sbumpc() is different than \n (that meaning the user entered a string smaller than 20 characters)?

Comment: cplusplus.com is generally recognized as a bad source of C++ information, because it uses outdated and ill-advised idioms. use cppreference.com instead.

Comment: @VinnieFalco: Hey this was from 2012 it looks like. I don't even remember when cppreference started its thing. :-) I will update the answer.

Comment: Now that's service!